# What is the best way to run some cleanup task after a chain of tasks are over

Tags: python, celery

I have a celery set up with multiple tasks all chained together. Something like this:

```
for i in n:
   a = a.si()
   ....
   mychain = chain(a, b, c, d)
   mychain.apply_async()
```

As you can see they are run for n times, creating n chains. My question is can i have one more task 'e'(kinda like a cleanup task - file, DB, etc), which will run after 'n' chains are done executing ? 
I could very well do it in the final iteration chaining at last, but is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You would want to use chords for this:

https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html

```
A chord is just like a group but with a callback. A chord consists of a 
header group and a body, where the body is a task that should execute after 
all of the tasks in the header are complete.
```

Comment: if it's just a a group, then it means there is no dependencies among tasks in the header group. I want to use chain since it provides a graph like dependencies and i just want to be able to perform a task after they are all over

Comment: you can chain within a chord